# Declaring a pointer to struct creates a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

It seems to me like `struct new_element *element = malloc(sizeof(*element))` creates a structure of type element, whereas I thought it would only create a pointer to it. The following code proves to me I'm wrong:

```
struct new_element
{
    int i;
    struct new_element *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct new_element *element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
    element->i = 5;
    element->next = NULL;
    printf("i = %d, next = %p\n", element->i, element->next);
}
```

Output:

```
i = 5, next = (nil);
```

`element->i` was given the value 5 and `element->next` was given the value `NULL`. Doesn't that mean that `element` points to a structure, which would mean that there *is* a structure that was created? I thought that `malloc` would only give a pointer the size needed in memory.

Comment: You thought wrong. Your question shows major missconceptions about pointers and `malloc` & friends. I'd strongly recommend to learn C from a good book. No online tutorial and definitively no obscure youtube videos.

Comment: What gave you reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: "*a pointer the size needed*" -- that's nonsense, a data pointer is a data pointer. `malloc()` returns a pointer to some usable memory of the size you specify.

Comment: It is unclear what you expected your declaration to do.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS why on earth would they want to do that? that'd allocate enough memory to store a pointer, not one of their structs

Comment: `struct new_element *element = malloc(sizeof(element))` allocates memory for a pointer to a struct, and also allocates memory for a struct. `struct new_element *element = malloc(sizeof(*element))` allocates memory for a pointer, and also allocates memory to a pointer (which will be pointed to by element). Am I right?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Huh? The code in the question is correct and less error prone.

Comment: @nounoursnoir  `sizeof(element)` gives the space needed by a pointer variable (which is independent of the struct you use) while `sizeof(*element)` this gives the size required by your structure

Comment: Code is `element->i = 5;` and post includes "element.i was given the value 5" --> `element.i` was not given a value, `element->i` was given a value.  `element` is a pointer.

Comment: @chux what did your previous comment mean, which is now deleted.

Comment: @chux true, I modified that ty

Comment: @nounoursnoir "element->i was given the value ... . Doesn't that mean that element is a structure".  --> If `element` was a structure, the `->` would be the wrong syntax.   As `element` is a pointer, `element->i` is correct.

Comment: @GAURANG VYAS  I earlier surmised your comments implied something that I did not see on review, so deleted my comment..

Comment: what I meant is that if `element->i` was given a value, it means that `element->i` exists, it is something, which would mean that element points to a structure, which has some memory allocated

Comment: @nounoursnoir Your question is good as it is asking about  `element` which is  a `struct new_element` pointer to sufficient  allocated memory and by implication, the difference between that and a `struct new_element xx`, where `xx` is a object of type `struct new_element`.

Comment: *"if `element->i` was given a value, it means that `element->i` exists":* this is not true; at least, not in the sense that you believe. If you had forgotten to initialize the pointer, it's still possible that you could have written to `element->i` and not realized your mistake until the program crashed, or worse. Therefore, although you were wrong, the behavior of the program you wrote doesn't prove the fact

Comment: "Am I right?" Absolutely not. Exactly the opposite is true. Given `struct new_element *element`, `malloc(sizeof(element))` allocates memory which is enough for one pointer, because `element` is a pointer. Whereas `malloc(sizeof(*element))` allocates memory which is enough for a `struct new_element`, because `*element` is a `struct new_element`.

Comment: ok so i guess the correct thing to do to allocate memory for a structure that `element` would point to is `struct new_element *element = malloc(sizeof(struct new_element))`, since `element` is a pointer to `struct new_element`, and `struct new_element` is a structure of type `new_element`

Comment: @nounoursnoir It's a matter of style, but `sizeof(struct new_element)` and `sizeof(*element)` will have the same value, and many people prefer the latter form, because it's more explicitly "the size of the thing pointed to by `element`".

Comment: @nounoursnoir Remember, `*` has more than one meaning. It has three meanings, in fact. It can be part of a type, it can be a pointer dereferencing operator, and it can be a multiplication operator, depending on context. (I'm not counting its other uses in comments, character constants, and string literals here.)

Comment: @IanAbbott that's a good thing to remember ty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `element` is a pointer.  When you define it, that sets aside space for the pointer.

If you just did this:

```
struct new_element *element;
```

You've created a pointer.  It just doesn't point anywhere.

When you then call `malloc(sizeof(*element))`, that sets aside space big enough for what `element` points to, i.e. an instance of `struct new_element`.  You then point the variable `element` to this section of memory.

This syntax:

```
element->i = 5;
```

Is the same as:

```
(*element).i = 5;
```

It dereferences the pointer `element`, giving you a `struct new_element`, then you access the member `i`.

If you did this, as you suggested in the comments:

```
struct new_element *element = malloc(sizeof(element));
```

You're not allocating the proper amount of space.  You're setting aside enough space for a `struct new_element *` instead of a `struct new_element`.  If the struct is larger than a pointer to it (likely in this case, since it contains a pointer to its own type), then you end of writing past the end of the allocated memory when modifying one of the members.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: A declaration does **not** reserve space. And the C language has no concept of a stack.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, that should be "define".  Fixed.

Comment: I removed the DV, but still not happy about adding the implementation detail. We really should not mix language and implementation.

Comment: @Olaf Fair enough.  Stack / heap isn't relevant to this particular question anyway.

Comment: @Olaf Do you know a C implementation without stack? Maybe it was relevant to speak about stack for an educational purpose.

Comment: @Boiethios [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller) processors I've used in 2017 use the stack only for the return address and not for parameter passing, so no stack for variables.

Comment: @Boiethios: As it happens, I do. The Cosmic toolchain for HC08 supported a mode which used static allocation of function parameters if there was no recursion (which is normally not used on that platform). For other CPUs there are similar implementations. Or all compilers for modern platforms which e.g. use registers. Said that: it does not matter and is irrelevant to answer the question. Mixing implementation and language is always a bad idea for beginner's questions.. Maybe you should accept there is more than x86 and ARM.